# What is usually taught after Linear Algebra and Real analysis?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice, learning

I am a self-learner who loves pure mathematics. I study mathematics alone without university and I don't have professor or advisor to help me  (So I am not sure what I can learn next). I mostly study math just for curiosity and I have learned calculus, real analysis, and linear algebra. I have read these books:

- Thomas’ Calculus (and Stewart's book).
- Half of Advanced Calculus by Patrick Fitzpatrick.
- Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert G. Bartle.
- Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin.
- Linear Algebra by Kenneth Hoffman and Ray Kunze.

I want to know what I can learn next **or in other words** What topics that I have their  pre requisite? I also don’t like real-world applications in mathematics; I prefer to learn the abstract concepts.

I know this question might have different answers depending on the school or professors, but I am pretty sure that these differences are not that big and many will agree on what I can learn  or I can’t learn  now. For example, I am sure that most people (or all) will agree that I can’t learn algebraic topology right now.
I was thinking of these topics:

- **Elementary Number Theory:** I don’t know if I should learn number theory now or later as I have heard that it uses many concepts from complex analysis and many special functions like $li(x)$.
- **Complex Analysis:** I think this will be a good complement to my real analysis books, but should I use Rudin’s Real and Complex Analysis or not? (By the way, I don’t know any other books on complex analysis).
- **ODE:** I don’t know if I should study this after or before complex analysis as I heard they use complex variables and I heard that most of this topic has to do with applications. As I mentioned before, I don’t like learning applications with new concepts; I like to learn the mathematical concepts in abstract.
- **General Topology:** I liked chapter 2 of Rudin’s book the most and it was about basic topology. I think real analysis is the only prerequisite, but I heard some people like Zach Star recommend a course in abstract algebra.
- **Abstract Algebra :** I heard that number theory is a prerequisite for this topic as many concepts involve (somehow) prime numbers.

There are other subjects I don’t know much (or anything) about: Combinatorics, Probability Theory, Graph Theory, Naive Set Theory, Measure Theory, Functional Analysis, and Fourier Analysis. But I think Combinatorics and Graph Theory are some of the options that I can study now.

Comment: all of those suggestions seem reasonable. also, probability theory, measure theory. you could also learn about manifolds if you like. really, it seems like you should just dive into different things and see how it goes.

Comment: @caitlin I totally forgot about measure theory and  I don't know anything abut  probability theory , Is it even a pure math subject ?

Comment: probability can be pure math, or it can be applied. i don't know you don't just try stuff. you obviously have an internet connection, so you can find out about this stuff yourself.

Comment: This is all relative. Depends of what you want you want to do,  what your school offers, and what you are advised to take for a round education. Even if it's in Mathematics  and what your school offers. Perhaps  mathematical physics,  information theory, probability and stochastic processes, mathematical finance, programming and numerical analysis, mathematical biology; perhaps abstract algebra...

Comment: @Mittens I just learn  pure math for curiosity and I want to know what can I learn now ? for example 

Can I learn  ODE now or Should I learn more about Complex analysis?
Can I learn topology now or should i first learn Abstract algebra ?
etc

Comment: hi there I am doing the exact thing you do, would you mind texting so we can get to know each  other well. I use discord how about ya?

Comment: At this point, you've got a lot of the basics down so you can proceed according to what you like. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Measure theory and group theory are two topics that might come up a lot regardless of your choice, so those could be good to keep in mind.

Comment: It's true that knowing some Number Theory is helpful when you come to study Abstract Algebra, but it's also true that knowing some Abstract Algebra is helpful when you come to study Number Theory. Helpful, not a prerequisite. Also, while some advanced branches of Number Theory require Complex Analysis, Elementary Number Theory does not.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What Number Theory book do you recommend? I was thinking of  number theory by niven zuckerman (because it is the only book that I know about Number Theory )

Comment: That's a very good text, especially the 5th edition where Montgomery joins the authors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what about ODE? what is the pre requisite for it ?.

Comment: @Mittens: "You should talk to your advisors at school." well I don't have any advisors since I am not a college math student .

Comment: Like most subjects, pie, it depends on the level. Wasn't there already some material on ODE in those Calculus books? Calculus is enough to make some useful progress in ODE, after a certain point the analysis prerequisites get heavier. Why not take yourself to a good library and see what textbooks in various subjects look like? Or go to a publisher's website, or to Amazon, to see what various textbooks say about their prerequisites?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at I.N Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, specifically to learn **Group Theory.** If you like the exposition to Group Theory, you can go through the rest of the book.

In my opinion, the subject is beautifully presented accompanied by an excellent set of problems. Also, the elementary number theory required for your study is present in the book or can be studied from other sources (not a hard task as not much depth is required).